Is this a good analogy for superdeterminism?
I am having a hard time wrapping my head around Superdeterminism. I know that it says that it violates statistical independence of measurement settings and particle behavior. But what exactly does this mean in layman terms?
Does it mean something along the line of if every time I yelled a dog in the other side of the world yelled? This would be a non local correlation but no randomness required or locality to be violated and the initial conditions of the universe would just have to be set up in a way where every time I yelled the dog did?

Somebody sends you a message from Earth light years away, you may yell or laugh at the contents. If you yell the dog barks back on Earth, if you laugh he squeals. The sender watches the dog and immediately knows your reaction. There is no superluminal communication. How? Because your reaction has been predetermined from the birth of time and this information propagated to both you and the dog at normal speeds. The dog is not reacting to your reaction, the fabric of the universe compels it just as it compels you. Superdeterminism is determinism for subjects that fancy themselves free willing.

Your analogy is one way superdeterminism can be. Superdeterminism can be set up by initial conditions in that way, yes.

Superdeterminism means that both yellings and the observations thereof were determined by the same hidden variable at the initial setup of the Universe.
This is a very problematic idea as the mechanism by which the actions of all these agents (and none of other's) are determined and sychronized at the initial setup is not described, only assumed.
In addition, randomness is required to determine the value of the hidden variable, unless a divine entity deciding the value, is assumed.

Superdeterminism means that before the measurement somehow the internal state of measurement instruments is correlated with your internal state in such a way as to reproduce the Bell correlations. The somehow is doing a lot of work here and there is currently no explanation of it according to advocates of superdeterminism:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.01324
Quantum theory without collapse already provides a local explanation of the Bell correlations
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9906007
https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.6223
and a lot else besides
https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.00568
So AFAICT superdeterminism exists solely to solve a set of problems that already have a solution and it lacks any explanation of the pre-existence of correlations.

Wait quantum theory without collapse may preserve locality in certain interpretations but it does not explain non local correlations or how they are maintained. If there was an explanation, we would be able to determine measurement results

But anyways, is my analogy similar to superdeterminism or?

@Stella Explain = give an account of what is happening in reality to produce the results. This is entirely compatible with not being able to predict the result of the measurement on each individual system.

@Stella The dog analogy is not entirely correct. It would be more like if you yell the dog yells and if you jump up and down on your hind legs the dog does likewise. The key issue is that what the dog does depends on what you do and this is somehow determined in advance.

So in quantum mechanics, what if a particular measurement setting causes a particular measurement result and isn’t just correlated to that measurement by some common cause in the past?

In QM measurement settings don't cause measurement results. In QM a measurement just produces a record of the information in an observable. It doesn't cause the observable to have some particular value.

@alanf, postulating an infinite number of invisible worlds might not be the best solution. Superdeterminism may achieve all that without any new physics.

@Andrei Superdeteminism by definition can't explain anything without new physics since it is new physics.

If you look at my answer above you will find that one proposal is Stochastic Electrodynamics. This theory does not postulate any new physics beyond classical electromagnetism.

@alanf If you look at my answer above you will find that one proposal is Stochastic Electrodynamics. This theory does not postulate any new physics beyond classical electromagnetism.

Superdeterminism was defined in the context of Bell's theorem. It says that the hidden variables (the properties of the entangled particles that are not described by standard quantum mechanics) and the measurement settings are not independent variables. Being a generic term it does not say how this correlation is achieved, you need to look at each proposed implementation for that.
Here are some examples:
– ’t Hooft’s cellular automaton interpretation
Explicit construction of Local Hidden Variables for any quantum theory up to any desired accuracy
https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.04335
– Wetterich’s probabilistic cellular automaton
Probabilistic cellular automata for interacting fermionic quantum field theories
https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.06366
– Stochastic electrodinamics
– Stochastic Electrodynamics: The Closest Classical Approximation to Quantum Theory
– https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.00996
You can see that all of the above examples are field theories. Such field theories impose global constraints upon the physical system. In the case of Stochastic Electrodynamics (which is in fact classical electrodynamics applied to the specific conditions of our universe - the existence of the zero-point field, the field behind Casimir's effect) you have Maxwell's equations. The requirement that the whole experimental setup in a Bell test has to satisfy Maxwell's equations implies that one cannot change the hidden variable (say the polarization of a photon) without also changing the state of the detectors. This is because a change of polarization requires some sort of change in the fields/charge distribution at the locus of the emission and such a change would require a corresponding global adjustment of the  electric/magnetic fields.
In this paper (7.6. The Violation of Bell Inequalities) a violation of Bell's inequalities by a local model (Stochastic electrodynamics) is presented:
https://www.mdpi.com/2673-9321/2/2/28#sec7dot6-foundations-02-00028
